# How to see again the latest dialog box in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, dialog

I was about to click on something, but then suddenly a dialogue box appeared. So my click went to the dialogue box without my intention. I even had no time to see its content. Is Windows 7 is such dangerous?

How can I bring back newest dialog boxes, so I can undo "my" choice?

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible for anyone to bring dialogue boxes back up to make a new choice for the most part.  Think about it:  The program has already accepted your input and moved on to a new state.

However, it seems as if you would benefit by making your cursor not automatically go to the dialogue box.  This can be done by opening the Control Panel and selecting Mouse, then going to the Pointer Options tab, and then making sure that "Automatically move pointer to the default button in a dialogue box" is deselected.

Comment: My mouse pointer did not automatically jump to that dialog box. The dialog box accidentally appeared under it. So why is Windows as insecure?

Comment: @gloschtla What do you mean by why is Windows as insecure?

Comment: Isn't it obvious? Imagine you want to click on anything. But before you reach the mouse button a dialog window appears accidentally. It appears so suddenly, that you cannot react with your finger, so you unintentionally click on something wrong.

Comment: I cannot believe that previous dialogs with windows were not logged. In other cases Microsoft offers the option to undo operations, such as bringing a file back to its original directory in Windows Explorer.

Comment: @gloschtla What software were you using?  Windows is not responsible for logging dialogue boxes; that is the program's job, if it even wants to.  I don't think any program or OS logs dialogue boxes and allows the user to undo decisions made by them.